# Can't use a second monitor with Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, budgie

I have an ASUS K501UX notebook model. Hardware: intel i7, intel 520 and nVidia 950M graphic cards.

When i try to use my second monitor through the HDMI port nothing happens. Ubuntu Budgie cant see the second monitor, in the Display Settings i always get only the first monitor.

Neither nVidia-settings can see the second monitor.

But if i use Windows10 the second monitor is recognized without problems.

I've already tried to

- update driver
- use the Nouveau drivers instead of the original nVidia drivers
- purge drivers and reinstall the previous version
- switch to intel graphic card and viceversa
- use aRandr but he cant see the second monitor

I think my HDMI is hardware disabled. Any idea to activate it?

EDIT: if i run

```
xrandr
```

i get

> HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

**2018 edit: Ubuntu 18.04 and later solved the bug**